# Xamarin Forms: How to get the SwipeDirection value from SwipeStarted event?

Tags: xamarin.forms, swipeview

I am using `swipeview` feature on my project for swiping the `flowlistviews`. I need both the left and right swipe for my center flowlistview. How can I achieve this on `swipeview`?

My code:

```
<SwipeView
    x:Name="SwipeView2"
    SwipeStarted="CenterSwipeView"
    IsVisible="False">
    <SwipeView.RightItems>
        <SwipeItems>
            <SwipeItem/>
        </SwipeItems>
    </SwipeView.RightItems>
    <flv:FlowListView>
        //listview items
    </flv:FlowListView>
</SwipeView>

public void CenterSwipeView(object sender, SwipeStartedEventArgs args)
{
  //how can I get the SwipeDirection value here
}
```

I need to call different functions based on the `SwipeDirection` value(left or right).

Also, I tried `SwipeGestureRecognizer` but it is not working for flowlistview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would better add `SwipeGestureRecognizer` on the `DataTemplate` instead of the whole FlowListView(otherwise it will be conflict with the default scroll event of listview).

```
<DataTemplate>
    <StackLayout BackgroundColor="LightBlue" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">

        <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
            <SwipeGestureRecognizer Direction="Left" Command="{Binding xxx}"/>
            <SwipeGestureRecognizer Direction="Right" Command="{Binding xxx}"/>
        </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>

        // the elements


    </StackLayout>  
</DataTemplate>
```

### Update

Since you handle the logic in Code Behind without using MVVM . You should use swipe event instead of command .

```
<StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
    <SwipeGestureRecognizer Direction="Left" Swiped="SwipeGestureRecognizer_Swiped"/>
</StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
```

```
private void SwipeGestureRecognizer_Swiped(object sender, SwipedEventArgs e)
{
   // set List2 ...
}
```

In addition, in your case the best solution is to use Tabbed Page . Which will support such a function in default .

Comment: I have tried this, but not working. I have created a sample, could you please have a look. https://drive.google.com/open?id=1k8XHyob5n_4Xft67Zy-vtwPH4t9Ba3hT

Comment: Currently, when tapping the labels on top of the page, the flowlistview shows on the UI one by one. I need the swiping of flowlistviews also here.

Comment: I have used the swiped event, but the event is not firing when swiping.

Comment: I am developing for all the platforms not only for android. Tabs are on the bottom for ios, so I can't do that here.

Comment: You could use the plugin https://www.nuget.org/packages/Naxam.TopTabbedPage.Forms/0.0.3.13-pre

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214312/discussion-between-sreejith-sree-and-lucas-zhang-msft).

Comment: As I said ,use tabbed page is the best way
For top tabbed you could install https://www.nuget.org/packages/Naxam.TopTabbedPage.Forms/0.0.3.13-pre for iOS